# Odoo - Extend context in xml rather than replace

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-14

I've been trying to inherit a form view and extend the context of a field rather than replace it completely. So far, the only thing I've been able to do is find out what the context is before I inherit (through looking at it in the UI of the database) and then copying those parameters in the inherited view. However, this isn't sustainable long-term for several reasons. One of the biggest being that if multiple modules will be adding context values, they would all need to be copied over each time.

Let's say I started with:

```
<record id="view_partner_form" model="ir.ui.view">
 <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
 <field name="model">res.partner</field>
               ...
   <field name="my_field" context="{'first_context_value': True}"/>

 </field>
</record>
```

Then I wanted to add `'second_context_value': False`, but keep the first context value there. Is there any way to accomplish this in xml when inheriting the form?

Answer (score 0):

To extend context (at least in Odoo 12.0) you should use a module written by OCA which is called **base_view_inheritance_extension**:

https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/12.0/base_view_inheritance_extension